# Find Comment by Author in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I want to make a Query in Azure DevOps.
The Goal is to track workitems where some specific user made a comment.

Perfect Query would be:
**Show all Workitems where latest/any Comment Author is @Me**

(„Latest“ is nice to have)

This would enable me to find Workitems where I asked a question but no one ever answered, so then I can act and ask again or whatever. I am also open for other solutions to solve this problem.