# Find comments made by particular author in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I want to find out all comments in a User Story/Task made by me in Azure DevOps which contain a certain text.

I know how to make a query that searches for a particular text (the relevant field is "History") but but it will return comments made by anyone.

I can narrow it down to tasks "Assigned To" me, but we usually assign tasks to the PO once they are resolved so the "Assigned To" field becomes useless. Since Azure shows me who made the comment, that info is stored in its db, but is available in its Query Editor?

Edit: A REST API solution would also work for me, if available.

[image]

Comment: Actually I found a similar question asked recently but it is unanswered :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68396530/find-comment-by-author-in-azure-devops

Comment: I don't think it's available in the query, you can find it with the rest api.

Comment: That would work too. What would be the REST API solution?

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can query the [Get Comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/get%20comments?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) Rest API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{workItemId}/comments?api-version=6.1-preview.3
```

In the results you will get every comment who created it.

If you want to query many work items in one call you can use [Get Comments Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/get%20comments%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) Api.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use query editor to add **history** for your query clause, comments entered into the discussion area can be queried. These are indexed for full text search.

```
Items I've been associated with
```

> History Contains Words MyName Or Assigned To Was Ever _ @Me

you can change that based on who you would like to search for using contains word of the username

for more you can learn from [Query By history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/history-and-auditing?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)

Comment: The "History Contains Words MyName" will give only work items that I mentioned in the comments, not comments that I wrote them.